# UIAnimation : Moving one view to another view in same viewcontroller by animation in ios7 through xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uianimation

> Hi first of all i know its  really a dumb question.I don't have any
>   experience in    UIAnimation so I stucked on it from long time. I am
>   making a application in which a viewcontroller contains lot of views.
>   No matter if they are in tableview, but for example if i clicked the
>   view which is in the 20th  position.So i want after clicking, the
>   selected view automatically moves with ANIMATION to the
>   first place and the view which was in the first place it shift to
>   second position by ANIMATION.I am trying to something like that. But
>   animation is fast and not beautiful.I want simple way to do it. Thanks in Advance

```
    NSArray *selectedCellIndices = [self.gView indicesOfSelectedCells];

    NSMutableArray *numbersToDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSNumber *indexToDelete in selectedCellIndices)
    [numbersToDelete addObject:[self.numbers objectAtIndex:[indexToDelete integerValue]]];

    //remove the entries from the data source
    [self.numbers removeObjectsInArray:numbersToDelete];
    //animate the cells leaving the gview
    [self.gView deleteCellsAtIndices:selectedCellIndices animated:YES];
    NSNumber *newNumber = [numbersToDelete objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.numbers insertObject:newNumber atIndex:0];
    [self.gView insertCellAtIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

> For animation i use something like that

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.30f delay:i*0.03f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                    CGRect frame = cell.frame;
                    frame.origin = newOrigin;

                    //cap how far it can move up so it doesn't just shoot off so quickly that it becomes invisible
    if (CGRectGetMaxY(cell.frame) - (newOrigin.y+CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)) > CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))
                    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMinY(cell.frame) - (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)+CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame));

                    cell.frame = frame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (index != finalCellIndex)
                    return;

                    completionBlock();
}];
```